# Need assistance with JS image event listener drawing multiple images on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Please help a newbie! I want to display in canvas: a rear image, followed by a front image, followed by a green rectangle. When it runs, it doesnt display all. When I click repeatedly on the "refresh" button, I can see the green rect for an instant, but gets covered over by the rear image. The front image shows up sporadically while clicking "refresh". I want to be able to display in-order, and manipulate the elements in drawScreen later. I guess I dont understand the "addEventListener" heirarchy. Notice the attempt to force the intended drawing sequence by using a drawScreen... but to no avail. Help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="484" style="border:2px solid     #000000;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
------------------------------
 external.js:
------------
window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded () {
    canvasApp();
}
function canvasApp() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var theBackImage = new Image();
    theBackImage.src = "supportArt/backImg.jpg";
theBackImage.addEventListener("load", function(){context.drawImage(theBackImage, 0, 0, 900, 484)}, false);

var theFrontImage = new Image();
theFrontImage.src = "supportArt/frontImg.jpg";
theFrontImage.addEventListener("load", function()    {context.drawImage(theFrontImage, 20, 20, 20, 20)}, false);

    drawScreen();

    function drawScreen(){
        context.drawImage(theBackImage, 0, 0, 900, 484)
        context.drawImage(theFrontImage, 20, 20, 20, 20)
        context.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
            context.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run `drawScreen` in your load function, instead of redrawing the image? As in, `theFrontImage.addEventListener("load", drawScreen);`. By the way, there's no "manipulating elements" once they're drawn. Your only option is to re-draw.

Comment: make a first loader function, that will wait or all your resources are fetched, then call one draw function in the painting order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not waiting for all the images to load before you do your first call the draw everything, then you draw the image by themselves when they are loaded which could be any order.

You need to wait till all the resources have loaded before you start drawing.

I have modified your code to do so. It counts the number of images you want to load and waits until that many images have loaded before calling the draw.

```
function canvasApp() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imagesToLoad = 0;  // number of images that you are loadin
    var imagesLoaded = 0;  // the number of images loaded
    function drawScreen() {  // draw the stuff
        context.drawImage(theBackImage, 0, 0, 900, 484)
        context.drawImage(theFrontImage, 20, 20, 20, 20)
        context.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
        context.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50)
    }

    var loaded = function(){  // event for image on load
        imagesLoaded += 1;    // add the image to the loaded count
        if(imagesLoaded === imagesToLoad){  // when the load count is the same as the images to load
            drawScreen();  // all load so draw;
        }
    }
    var loadImage = function(url){  // load an image
        var image = new Image();   
        image.addEventListener("load",loaded);
        imagesToLoad += 1;  // add to the number of images we want to load
        image.src = url;
        return image;  // return the image;
    }


    var theBackImage = loadImage("supportArt/backImg.jpg");
    var theFrontImage = loadImage("supportArt/frontImg.jpg");

}
```